# C# client authenticate PHP soap server

Tags: c#, php, visual-studio, soap, wsdl

I want to authenticate user using C# client, but nothing works. I'm new with visual studio so i don't know all functionality ;/ My basic button event:

```
        using System;
    using System.Collections.Generic;
    using System.ComponentModel;
    using System.Data;
    using System.Drawing;
    using System.Linq;
    using System.Net;
    using System.Text;
    using System.Threading.Tasks;
    using System.Windows.Forms;

    namespace WindowsFormsApplication1
    {
        public partial class Form1 : Form
        {
            public Form1()
            {
                InitializeComponent();
            }

            private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
            {
                localhost.Calculator client = new localhost.Calculator();

                string returnString = client.Average(10,8);
                //System.Diagnostics.Debug.Write(rep);
                label1.Text = returnString;
            }
        }
    }
```

My server.php file :

```
        <?php
    ini_set("soap.wsdl_cache_enabled", "0");

    class Server{

        protected $class_name = '';

        public function __construct($class_name)
        {
            $this->class_name = $class_name;
        }

        public function authenticate ($username, $password)
        {
            if ($username != 'admin' && $password != 'admin') return false;
            else return true;
        }

        public function log($method_name,$data)
        {
            $filename = 'log.txt';
            $handle = fopen($filename, 'a+');
            fwrite($handle, date("l dS of F Y h:i:s A").' - '.$_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR']."\r\n".$method_name."\r\n".print_r($data,true));
            fclose($handle);
        }

        public function __call($method_name, $parameters)
        {
            $this->log($method_name,$parameters); //  log

            if(!$this->authenticate($_SERVER['PHP_AUTH_USER'], $_SERVER['PHP_AUTH_PW']))
            {

            }
            else
            {
                if(!method_exists($this->class_name, $method_name ))
                    return 'Method '.$method_name.' not found'; // methot exist check

                return call_user_func_array(
                        array($this->class_name, $method_name ),
                        $parameters
                ); //call method    
            }
        }
    }


    class Calculator {
        public function Average ($parameters)
        {
            $num1 = $parameters->num1;
            $num2 = $parameters->num2;

            return self::AverageResponse(($num1 + $num2) / 2);
        }

        public function AverageResponse ($message)
        {
            return ['Result' => $message];
        }

        public function Minus ($parameters)
        {
            $num1 = $parameters->num1;
            $num2 = $parameters->num2;

            return self::MinusResponse($num1 - $num2);
        }

        public function MinusResponse ($message)
        {
            return ['Result' => $message];
        }
    }

    class in {

    }

    $Service = new Server('Calculator');
    $classmap=[
        'in' => 'in'
    ];
    $server = new SOAPServer('http://localhost:9080/soap-websiteservice-wsdl/Calculator.wsdl', array(
        'soap_version' => SOAP_1_2,
        'style' => SOAP_RPC,
        'use' => SOAP_LITERAL,
        'classmap'=>$classmap
    ));
    $server->setObject($Service);
    //$server->setClass('Calculator');
    $server->handle();
```

Php client authentication works. Code:

```
    <?php
    // client.php
    $options = array(
        'trace' => true,
        'login' => 'admin',
        'password' => 'admin'
    );
    $client = new SOAPClient('http://localhost:9080/soap-websiteservice-wsdl/server.php?wsdl', $options);

    echo "Average: \r\n";
    var_dump($client->Average(['num1' => 10, 'num2' => 6])->Result);

    echo "Minus: \r\n";
    var_dump($client->Minus(['num1' => 10, 'num2' => 6])->Result);
```

wsdl:

```
        <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="no"?>
    <wsdl:definitions xmlns:soap="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/wsdl/soap/" xmlns:tns="http://localhost:9080/soap-websiteservice-wsdl/Calculator" xmlns:wsdl="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/wsdl/" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" name="Calculator" targetNamespace="http://localhost:9080/soap-websiteservice-wsdl/Calculator">
      <wsdl:types>
        <xsd:schema targetNamespace="http://localhost:9080/soap-websiteservice-wsdl/Calculator">
          <xsd:element name="Average">
            <xsd:complexType>
              <xsd:sequence>
                <xsd:element name="num1" type="xsd:int" />
                <xsd:element name="num2" type="xsd:int"></xsd:element>
              </xsd:sequence>
            </xsd:complexType>
          </xsd:element>
          <xsd:element name="AverageResponse">
            <xsd:complexType>
              <xsd:sequence>
                <xsd:element name="Result" type="xsd:string"/>
              </xsd:sequence>
            </xsd:complexType>
          </xsd:element>

          <xsd:complexType name="AverageRequestType">
            <xsd:sequence>
                <xsd:element name="num1" type="xsd:int"></xsd:element>
                <xsd:element name="num2" type="xsd:int"></xsd:element>
            </xsd:sequence>
          </xsd:complexType>
          <xsd:element name="Minus">
            <xsd:complexType>
                <xsd:sequence>

                    <xsd:element name="num1" type="xsd:int"></xsd:element>
                    <xsd:element name="num2" type="xsd:int"></xsd:element>
                </xsd:sequence>
            </xsd:complexType>
          </xsd:element>
          <xsd:element name="MinusResponse">
            <xsd:complexType>
                <xsd:sequence>

                    <xsd:element name="Result" type="xsd:string"></xsd:element>
                </xsd:sequence>
            </xsd:complexType>
          </xsd:element>
          <xsd:element name="AverageFault">
            <xsd:complexType>
                <xsd:sequence>

                    <xsd:element name="AverageFault" type="xsd:string"></xsd:element>
                </xsd:sequence>
            </xsd:complexType>
          </xsd:element>
          <xsd:element name="AverageFault1">
            <xsd:complexType>
                <xsd:sequence>

                    <xsd:element name="AverageFault" type="xsd:string"></xsd:element>
                </xsd:sequence>
            </xsd:complexType>
          </xsd:element>
        </xsd:schema>
      </wsdl:types>
      <wsdl:message name="AverageRequest">
        <wsdl:part element="tns:Average" name="parameters"/>
      </wsdl:message>
      <wsdl:message name="AverageResponse">
        <wsdl:part element="tns:AverageResponse" name="parameters"/>
      </wsdl:message>
      <wsdl:message name="MinusRequest">
        <wsdl:part name="parameters" element="tns:Minus"></wsdl:part>
      </wsdl:message>
      <wsdl:message name="MinusResponse">
        <wsdl:part name="parameters" element="tns:MinusResponse"></wsdl:part>
      </wsdl:message>
      <wsdl:message name="AverageFault">
        <wsdl:part name="parameters" element="tns:AverageFault"></wsdl:part>
      </wsdl:message>
      <wsdl:message name="AverageFault1">
        <wsdl:part name="parameters" element="tns:AverageFault1"></wsdl:part>
      </wsdl:message>
      <wsdl:portType name="Calculator">
        <wsdl:operation name="Average">
          <wsdl:input message="tns:AverageRequest"/>
          <wsdl:output message="tns:AverageResponse"/>

            </wsdl:operation>
        <wsdl:operation name="Minus">
            <wsdl:input message="tns:MinusRequest"></wsdl:input>
            <wsdl:output message="tns:MinusResponse"></wsdl:output>
        </wsdl:operation>
      </wsdl:portType>
      <wsdl:binding name="CalculatorSOAP" type="tns:Calculator">
        <soap:binding style="document"
            transport="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/http" />
        <wsdl:operation name="Average">
            <soap:operation
                soapAction="http://localhost:9080/soap-websiteservice-wsdl/Calculator/NewOperation" />
            <wsdl:input>
                <soap:body use="literal" />
            </wsdl:input>
            <wsdl:output>
                <soap:body use="literal" />
            </wsdl:output>
        </wsdl:operation>
        <wsdl:operation name="Minus">
            <soap:operation
                soapAction="http://localhost:9080/soap-websiteservice-wsdl/Calculator/Minus" />
            <wsdl:input>
                <soap:body use="literal" />
            </wsdl:input>
            <wsdl:output>
                <soap:body use="literal" />
            </wsdl:output>
        </wsdl:operation>
      </wsdl:binding>
      <wsdl:service name="Calculator">
        <wsdl:port binding="tns:CalculatorSOAP" name="CalculatorSOAP">
          <soap:address location="http://localhost:9080/soap-websiteservice-wsdl/server.php"/>
        </wsdl:port>
      </wsdl:service>
    </wsdl:definitions>
```

Comment: I assume you're getting an error message, you might want to include that.

Comment: Here is no erros. I just dont know hot to send login and passwort from c# client to php soap server. In example you can see php client and where i can easy send login and password

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I get it!

My all SOAP SERVER and Client files: [enter link description here](http://www.filedropper.com/soap-websiteservice-wsdl)
Files in archive: wsdl, server.php, client.php, CalculatorService.php, Calculator.php, Average.php, log.txt

In results you can see
[image]

Also client is authorized!